# Copy generic list value to another generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo, generic-list

I have this webmethod.

```
   [WebMethod]
    public List<BlogCultureInfo> loadCultureList()
    {
        List<Language> lstAllCultures = LocaleController.GetCultures();//Its bring a value from cultureInfo
        List<SCultureInfo> lstCulture = new List<SCultureInfo>();
        SCultureInfo objInfo = new SCultureInfo();
        foreach (Language objLst in lstAllCultures)
        {

            objInfo.LanguageName = objLst.LanguageName;
            objInfo.LanguageCode = objLst.LanguageCode;

            lstCulture.Add(objInfo);
        }
        return lstCulture;

    }
```

Its run without any error.When I debug In `lstAllCultures` it bring correct value.210 different cultureinfo value.But after loop when I see `lstCulture` it have last value of `lstAllCultures`.[image]

What I am doing wrong .Thanks.

Comment: SCultureInfo objInfo = new SCultureInfo(); //move that into the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to create the new object(SCultureInfo ) inside the loop, not outside.

```
foreach (Language objLst in lstAllCultures)
        {
            SCultureInfo objInfo = new SCultureInfo();
            objInfo.LanguageName = objLst.LanguageName;
            objInfo.LanguageCode = objLst.LanguageCode;
            lstCulture.Add(objInfo);
        }
```

In your original code you have only one object, added in the list multiple times and holding the values assigned in the last iteration of foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
foreach (Language objLst in lstAllCultures)
  {
  SCultureInfo objInfo = new SCultureInfo();
  objInfo.LanguageName = objLst.LanguageName;
  objInfo.LanguageCode = objLst.LanguageCode;
  lstCulture.Add(objInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you instantiated objInfo outside the foreach loop, and by adding the object in the list, you are only adding the REFERENCE of the object, and any modification to the object in your foreach loop would then be applied to all references in the list.

How about move the line

```
 SCultureInfo objInfo = new SCultureInfo();
```

inside foreach loop

```
  foreach (Language objLst in lstAllCultures)
```

Does it work serve the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same `objInfo` instance to the list for every `lstAllCultures`. Looks like `LanguageName` and `LanguageCode` are reference types. hence every time you assign a new value to `objInfo` it updates the instance with the value and as it is added to multiple times, you are seeing the same value repeated.

To fix this, create a new `objInfo` every time inside the foreach like

```
foreach (Language objLst in lstAllCultures)
{
    SCultureInfo objInfo = new SCultureInfo();
    objInfo.LanguageName = objLst.LanguageName;
    objInfo.LanguageCode = objLst.LanguageCode;
    lstCulture.Add(objInfo);
}
```